# Count n days, skipping specified dates

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to figure out the best way to calculate which day is n days from now, but excluding a certain set of dates from being counted (Postal Service holidays/Sundays).

```
For example, 5 days from December 20th:
Dec 21st = 1
Dec 22nd = 2
Dec 23rd = skipped (Sunday)
Dec 24th = 3
Dec 25th = skipped (Xmas)
Dec 26th = 4
Dec 27th = 5
```

My setup will be a table with starting dates, a table to determine the number of days it each type of record should count, and a table to list the days that should be excluded from counting (Sundays are not included in this list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a stored function -

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_a_day(start_date DATE, n INT)
  RETURNS date
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE end_date DATE DEFAULT start_date;
  WHILE i < n DO
    SET end_date = end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY;

    -- Create 'holidays' table!
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @holydays FROM holidays WHERE date = end_date;

    IF @holydays = 0 AND DAYOFWEEK(end_date) <> 1 THEN
      SET i = i + 1;
    END IF;
  END WHILE;

  RETURN end_date;
END
```

Create a `holydays` table with Postal Service holidays.

Comment: This works perfectly. It may be a bit slow with a ton of records, but it allows me to use the built-in date functionality in a simple function. Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to improve preformance
by first calculating the date range: `Start-date` through `End-date = Start-date + n days`. Set `i` to `n` minus the number
of skip days between Start-date and End-date (one hit to the database). Run the rest of the loop as-is. The number
of iterations, and subsequent database hits, is now limited to the number of days skipped.

Answer (score 1):

The "best" way depends on your implementation context, of course.

(1) If you have a small number of starting dates, you could proceed along the lines you're following now.

```
for each startingDate
    counter = 0
    advanceDate = startingDate
    do while counter < nOfBusinessDays
        advanceDate  = advanceDate.addDays(1) # whatever your environment provides for date arithmetic
        if advanceDate is found in tableOfSundays # see (a) below
            continue
        if advanceDate is found in tableOfHolidays
            continue
        counter++
    end do while
    # advanceDate is nOfBusinessDays later than startingDate
end for each
```

(a) If your date arithmetic package provides a day-of-week function, you can use that for the Sunday test.

(2) If you have a lot of starting dates that you need to evaluate, and/or you will compute the same date-plus-days repeatedly, you could precompute a map of business days.  The map would cover the span of time between the earliest starting date in your table and the latest starting date, plus the maximum number of business days to count and plus any intervening Sundays and holidays.  Implement the map as an ordinary array in ascending date order.  Then counting off business days from a starting date is just a question of array indexes.

(3) You could implement a hybrid solution, using method (1) to begin, then caching answers in the method (2) map.  (This solves the boundary problem of how to figure out what the latest day in the map should be.)

Comment: I suppose i should have clarified quantities. I could potentially be running 100,000 or more per day through this. They would be calculated at the time of import or at the time of an update to the holidays. I think the simplest way would just be to generate a table with all of the days between the earliest date and something beyond this applications life cycle (like your option #2) and just flag days that are to be skipped. I feel like im reinventing the wheel by bypassing the built in date functions, though...